# Spring Dependency Injection usage

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I'm still learning about the Spring Framework and I'm trying to really get a good understanding of when and how to use Dependency Injection

Should all dependencies be managed via Interfaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use interfaces for dependencies that expose an API of some sort and that have an implementation that may need to be swapped out (e.g. using mocks in unit tests). One common case is the DAO (data access object), which in Spring Data refers to as a Repository, which ties your data model to a persistence layer. Another common case is a Service which exposes operations on your domain model. Typically a Service will depend on the data access layer, so to unit test the service you will mock the DAO/repository. Another example is a third-party service; these are often only used by production systems, but must be simulated in development and testing environments. In this case, an interface is far superior to, say, embedding boolean flags in your code and hoping you don't have any logic errors.

The key thing to remember about managing dependencies is actually managing your use of the `new` keyword. Any time you use `new`, you are creating a dependency on an implementation. The goal of dependency injection is to separate how you *use* things you depend on with how you *get* them. You can depend on either an interface or a class, for a simple, obvious reason: Java supports subclassing. So even if you depend on a class instead of an interface, you might end up with a *subclass*. Spring framework actually does this automatically in many cases.

If you find yourself needing to create objects and you're not sure that you should depend on them, have your dependency injection framework give you a Factory for those objects. How this works is obviously framework-dependent, but all frameworks that I know of support factories. If you're not using a framework, you can still write factories and use them instead of using `new` all the time.

Answer (score 1):

If you write a code without using spring IOC container, you have to write some factory classes to create objects and hook them up. For an example instance consider a service class which has a reference to the DAO instance. You have to write some initialization factory for the service class which guarantees a singleton access to the service class and makes sure that the service class is instantiated with an instance of DAO. Creating new instances everywhere in your code is not a good practice, hence factory pattern is used. But if you use Spring IOC container it will take care of all these things. Usually it creates singleton instances so you don't need to use `new` keyword in your code lending you to write more clear code. Your code is loosely coupled and more maintainable with this approach. If you have only one public constructor you can now have the liberty of doing a constructor injection, without using `@Autowire` invasive annotation with the new spring version.

There are three DI mechanisma used in spring as stated [here](http://vojtechruzicka.com/field-dependency-injection-considered-harmful/). Out of the three constructor injection is recommended since it is more testable and does not lead to any invariant. Field injection using `@Autowire` is evil and not recommended since it is not testable solution.

Hope this helps. Happy coding.